# Conditional Expected Value- maximum and minimum

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have to compute $E(max(X,Y)|min(X,Y)=t)$ where X and Y are independent and have uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

I made this task:

$E(max(X,Y)|min(X,Y)=t)=f(t)$

$E(max(X,Y)\mathbf{1}_{min(X,Y)>s})=Ef(min(X,Y))\mathbf{1}_{min(X,Y)>s}$

$\int_{s}^{1}x*2xdx=\int_{s}^{1}f(x)*(2-2x)dx$

$2s^2=f(s)*(2-2s)$

$f(s)=(2-2s)/2s^2$

But the answer is diffrent. Where did I mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54505/distribution-of-maxx-i-mid-minx-i-when-x-i-are-i-i-d-uniform-random-var.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281908/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you computed your left-hand side incorrectly.

$$E[\max(X,Y) 1_{\min(X,Y) > s}] = \int_s^1 \int_x^1 y \, dy \, dx + \int_s^1 \int_y^1 x \, dx \, dy = \int_s^1 (1-t^2) \, dt$$

Setting the integrand equal to $f(t) 2(1-t)$ yields $f(t) = \frac{1+t}{2}$.

---

Alternate approach:

$$\begin{align}E[\max(X,Y) \mid \min(X,Y) = t]
&= \int_0^\infty P(\max(X,Y) \ge u \mid \min(X,Y) = t) \, du
\\
&= \int_0^t 1 \, du + \int_t^1 \frac{2(1-u)}{2(1-t)} \, du
\\
&= t + \frac{(1-t)^2 / 2}{1-t} = t + \frac{1-t}{2} = \frac{1 + t}{2}.
\end{align}$$